# How do you secure server side variables and secrets?

Tags: webserver, admin, administration

What are good practices for securing server side variables that may vary on each deployment, such as api keys and salts and so forth? Not only considering good isolation but also securing them however they may be stored.

Answer (score 0):

by just dont telling other .... and by securing your ftp username and password otherwise no one can access the variable and secrets

since its  server it will run on server and than html will generated so user will not able to see these